# GPO/Script setting screen Resolution to all domain

Tags: group-policy, screen-resolution

Hi I have a closed domain that I can not add any new utility/software and I would like to set the same resolution to all the computers but have found there no good way using GPO is there a another way? Hopefully using VBS. I have read about changing the regestriy keys but will it work for different computers with different hardware? Is there any other option?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use [Powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/07/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-change-my-desktop-monitor-resolution-via-windows-powershell.aspx) or [VBScript](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Changing-Screen-Reolution-m2802.aspx) to call the appropriate Windows API functions. If you do not want to mess with scripting, you could use a [third-party utility like qres/resswitch](http://www.naughter.com/qres.html)

Comment: can not add any new utility/software as i said

Comment: @yaarzeigerman qres does not need local installation, it would run off any share. But if it suits your needs better, you surely could take the scripting approach - it is somewhat cumbersome though.